# javascript error for the textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script   type ="text/javascript" >

function toggletr()
{
debugger;
var Inputs =$get("TextBox1");
}
</script>
```

i  trying    this   i am  getting   error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

but in  textbox  it  contains    value

```
//var Inputs = document .getElementById ("TextBox1");
```

if i do like this i am getting the value.
can  any  one  tell me  how  to  solve this  one in javscript using `$get()`  or JQuery
 how  to  assign value

thank  you

Comment: inorder  to use 
var Inputs =$get("TextBox1"); we need to have  an script  manager
if this  is not there  then we get this error
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">

    </asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: @prince23: did you just answer your own question then?

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure the definition of the `toggletr` function appears earlier in the document than calls to it.  Try it with the `toggletr` function defined in the `<head>` section of your page if it isn't already.